# How to create an async reducer with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm new to Angular and I'm working on setting up an asynchronous reducer to make API calls in my application. My goal is to load files from an API when the loadFiles action is triggered.

I created a function returnDatas which uses Axios to make the API call and return the data. This function is asynchronous to handle waiting for API response. However, when I call this function in my reducer, the returned value seems to be a promise instead of the actual API response.

My reducer looks like this:

```js
export const initialState = {
    files : sessionStorage.getItem('files') ||  [],
    test: 0
};
const returnDatas = async (data: any) => {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', data);
    
    try {
        const res =  await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/uploads', form )
        console.log (res)
        return res

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return 0
    }
}

export const filesReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(FilesActions.increment, (state) => {

        console.log('filesReducer increment')

        return {
            ...state,
            test: state.test + 1
        }
    }),
    on(FilesActions.loadFiles, (state, action) => {
        const data = action.data
        const res = returnDatas(data)
        console.log(res, 'filesReducer loadFiles')

        return {
            ...state,
            files: []
        }
    }
    )

);
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at ngrx effects?

Comment: Try looking into [NgRx-Effect](https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/effects). While they may be confusing at first, they are nothing more than an action listening on other actions and executing after the call of the 1. action. Sound's complicated, really isn't though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A reducer is always synchronous within an NgRx application.
For side effects/asynchronous "stuff" you can rely on [`@ngrx/effects`](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects).